# Jersey REST Application 500 internal server error on GET

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I use the following method to receive a XML/JSON response

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) // {"application/json", "application/xml"}
public Group getIt() {

    groups= new ArrayList<>();
    groups.add(new Group("Group1"));
    groups.add(new Group("Group2"));
    groups.add(new Group("Group3"));
    groups.add(new Group("Group4"));

    return groups.get(1);

}
```

When I visit .../path, nothing gets displayed in my browser. Upon inspecting the Header, it seems that I am getting a "500 Internal server error". Why does my browser not display a JSON representation of the second group object and why do I get the error? (same result when trying to produce an XML)

(I should add that I am using the correct path)

-I just noticed, that the HTTP head doesn't specify a Content type. Why? I thought that this is what `@Produces` does

Comment: 500 Internal server error means there is something wrong in your server. Can you post the stack traces for the exception in your server?

Comment: @Wilson SEVERE: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/xml, type=class com.classes.Group, genericType=class com.classes.Group.

Comment: according to this website http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/download-xml-with-jersey-jaxb/

the jersey-server.jar should be enough (which I have)